# I Have: setContentView(cv) but Need: setContentView(R.layout.arc_timer_activity) - does not work

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-activity

I have a problem. I'd like to use layout for designe this ArcTimerActivity.
When I change `setContentView(cv)` to `setContentView(R.layout.arc_timer_activity)`  IT DOES NOT WORK. (I'm not programmer, so its not easy for me)

```
public class ArcTimerActivity extends Activity implements Runnable, View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {

    private ArcTimerView cv = null;
    private Thread t = null;
    private boolean run_thread = false;
    private int run_thread_fps = 50; // Max 1000

    private IntervalSession is;

    private final int MENU_PREFERENCES = 15;

    //@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);


        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        is = new IntervalSession();
        restorePreferences();

        cv = new ArcTimerView(this, is);

        cv.setOnClickListener(this);
        cv.setOnLongClickListener(this);

        restoreRunningState(getLastNonConfigurationInstance());

        setContentView(cv);
    }


   ....................
```

IF USE setContentView(R.layout.arc_timer_activity) - NO ERRORS, JUST Black SCREEN. Maby I need smth to add or change to display Activity in layout?

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"

 >

 <View
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
></View>

  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do not post the same question again and again .

Comment: *NO ERRORS, JUST Black SCREEN* - And what you would expect to see on the screen? You just put an empty `View` in a `LinearLayout`.

Comment: I'd like to display my Activity in layout

Comment: Are you drawing anything in your ArcTimerView ?

Comment: Displaying graphic timer (clock)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First give a specific id to any layout let say View in your xml file where you want to add that cv (or IntervalSession()).

Now setContentView(R.layout.arc_timer_activity);

Now, define object of Resource View like below:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"

 >

 <View
android:id="@+id/myView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
></View>

  </LinearLayout>
```

Now in Jva file give resources to that id

```
View myView = (View) findViewById(R.id.myView);
```

Now create object of the view you want to add.

```
cv = new ArcTimerView(this, is);
```

and add that to your View.

```
myView.add(cv); // or myView.addView(cv);
invalidate();
```

This way you can add any view dynamically to your resource layout.

Feel free for any comments.

**UPDATE**

There is one of my project Demo in which i have implemented as like your requirement. See code snippet below. MyView is the call to whom i have added. Concentrate on it.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(new MyView(this)); // Edited
    statusString="testing Post For Application Development"; 
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    drawingLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawingLayout);
    System.out.println("The Layout is: "+drawingLayout);
    myView = new MyView(this);
    drawingLayout.addView(myView);

    display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    // Setting mPaint 
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(7);
```

In above code, MyView is the class to whom i want to add in to the layout. Please refer that code and you will ge how i have add MyView class object in to the layout.

Hope this code help you.

Comment: Its my Hardcoded syntax so please check there might be some speling mistake only. and instead of add() you can use addView().

Comment: So hope it help you. You can also upvote. So it can help other.